# Inside html how to check whether any variable is boolean or not, through angular expression?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an element inside my html where i have to check type of an variable, whether its boolean or not.

```
<button process-indicator="{{typeof(button.processIndicator) === 'boolean' ? 'modalProcess' : 'modalClose'}}"/>
```

here process indicator is my directive. But in my case its always setting value to 'modalClose'.

What I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Try to do the logic in a function and return the respective indicator value. [Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/va893opr/1/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since **typeof()** is a JavaScript function, and **{{  }}** are for **Angular** expression execution, so we are not able to execute JavaScript code or function inside Angular expressions.

To make this happen we need to assign the result value to some **$scope variable** so that it can be utilised inside our HTML using Angular expressions.

We have to do something similar to explain above by @anpsmn in his fiddle.
Which is :

**HTML :**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="testCtrl">
<p process-indicator="{{checkType()}}">Value: {{checkType()}}</p>
```

**Controller :**

```
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("testCtrl",['$scope', function($scope){

$scope.processIndicator = false;

$scope.checkType = function() {
    return typeof($scope.processIndicator)==='boolean'? 'modalProcess' : 'modalClose';
}; 

}])
```